# How can I recursively replace a string in file and directory names?

Tags: shell, find, rename, xargs

I have a git clone of etckeeper, and I'm trying to rename all files and directories with `etckeeper` in the name to `usrkeeper`. For example, `./foo-etckeeper-bar` should be renamed to `./foo-usrkeeper-bar`.

Finding the relevant files is trivial:

```
% find . -path '*etckeeper*' -print
```

However, I can't figure out how to actually do the renaming. I tried combining `xargs` with `mv`:

```
% find . -path '*etckeeper*' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -J % bash -c mv % '$(echo' % \| sed \"s/etckeeper/usrkeeper/\" \)
```

For readability, the non-escaped second half reads: `xargs -0 -n 1 -J % bash -c mv % $(echo % | sed "s/etckeeper/usrkeeper/" )`. The idea behind it is that we use `$()` to pipe the filename through `sed`, which is used to do the replacement.

The issue here is that `bash -c` requires the command to execute to be a single string. After that, it starts interpreting arguments as positional parameters. I could quote the whole thing:

```
% find . -path '*etckeeper*' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -J % bash -c 'mv % $(echo % | sed "s/etckeeper/usrkeeper/g" )'
```

But now `xargs` won't replace `%`. How can I solve this? (Also, as a side note, the above will fail if there's a file containing `etckeeper` in the name in a directory containing `etckeeper` in the name, because the directory will be moved before the file.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the rename command (see **edit 1**).

**Solution 1**

For a reasonable number of files/directory, by setting bash 4 option [globstar](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (not works on recursive name, see **edit 3**):

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -n 's/etckeeper/userkeeper/g' **
```

**Solution 2**

For a big number of files/directories using rename and find in two steps to prevent failed rename on files in just renamed directories (see **edit 2**):

```
find . -type f -exec rename 's/etckeeper/userkeeper/g' {} \;
find . -type d -exec rename 's/etckeeper/userkeeper/g' {} \;
```

**EDIT 1:**

[There are two different rename commands](http://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2011/12/a-tale-of-two-renames.html).
This answer uses the Perl-based rename command, available in Debian-based distros. To have it on a not Debian based distro you [can install from cpan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32862278/1667104) or grab it around.

**EDIT 2:**

As pointed out by Jeff Schaller in the comments the `-depth` find option `Process each directory's contents before the directory itself` so only an "ordered" find by `-depth` option would be enough:

```
find . -depth -exec rename 's/etckeeper/userkeeper/g' {} \;
```

**EDIT 3**

Solution 1 doesn't work for recursive rename targets, (es. `etckeeper/etckeeper/etckeeper`) becasue outer levels are processed before inner levels and pointer to inner levels become useless. (After the first rename `etckeeper/etckeeper/etckeeper` will be named `usrkeeper/etckeeper/etckeeper` so the rename for `etckeeper/etckeeper/` and `etckeeper/etckeeper/etckeeper` will fail). The same problem fixed in `find` by `-depth` options.

**EDIT4**

As pointed out in the comments by cas, *I'd use {} + rather than {} \; - forking a perl script like rename multiple times (once per file/dir) is expensive.*

Comment: man. I wish I knew about `rename` before I wrote that 80+ character oneliner. nice tip.

Comment: rename is a sort of underdog command.

Comment: as much as I'd like to accept my own answer, this is clearly more elegant. (plus, I won't get rep, but you will.) kudos.

Comment: Haven't tested this, but would the 'directory' `find` need -depth if there are subdirectories named etckeeper/etckeeper ?

Comment: +1.  but I'd use `{} +` rather than `{} \;` - forking a perl script like `rename` multiple times (once per file/dir)  is expensive.

Comment: The -depth command actually did not process dir contents before renaming dir itself. I just tested this. Running the same command a second time did, of course, so it's no biggy, but still..

Answer (score 1):

Your original question is actually pretty easy to answer: `xargs` (at least on OS X) has an `-I` option, too, which does *not* require that the replacement string be a unique argument. So, the invocation simply becomes:

```
% find . -path '*etckeeper*' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -I % bash -c 'echo mv % $(echo % | sed "s/etckeeper/usrkeeper/g" )'
```

Easy peasy. Now, let's rename in the correct order. As it turns out, `find` will print directories first (because it has to process them before it descends into them), so all we need to do is reverse the order of the filenames:

```
% find . -path '*etckeeper*' -print | tail -r | xargs -n 1 -I % bash -c 'echo mv % $(echo % | sed "s/etckeeper/usrkeeper/g" )'
```

Note that I've switched `find -print0 | xargs -0` for `find -print | xargs`. Why? Because `tail -r` reverses based on newlines, not null characters. If you didn't switch it, `tail -r` would print out the same thing you piped into it! So the script is more correct now, but also it will break on filenames that contain e.g. newlines.

Note that if you don't have `tail -r`, you should try `tac`. See: [How can I reverse the order of lines in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/742466/1198896) on Stack Overflow.

Now, the issue is that the `sed` command is too aggressive. For example, with a tree like:

```
.
├── etckeeper-foo
│   └── etckeeper-bar.md
└── some-other-directory
    └── etckeeper-baz.md
```

You'll get `mv` invocations that look like:

```
mv ./some-other-directory/etckeeper-baz.md ./some-other-directory/usrkeeper-baz.md
mv ./etckeeper-foo/etckeeper-bar.md ./usrkeeper-foo/usrkeeper-bar.md
mv ./etckeeper-foo ./usrkeeper-foo
```

The first one's fine, but the second one's clearly not - since we haven't yet done `mv ./etckeeper-foo ./usrkeeper-foo`!

Let's only replace in the *last* pathname component. We can do this by using `basename` and `dirname`:

```
% find . -name '*etckeeper*' -print | tail -r | xargs -n 1 -I % bash -c 'echo mv % $(dirname %)/$(basename % | sed "s/etckeeper/usrkeeper/g" )'
```

Note that the other change I've made is using `find -name`, not `find -path`.

This produces the correct `mv` invocations:

```
mv ./some-other-directory/etckeeper-baz.md ./some-other-directory/usrkeeper-baz.md
mv ./etckeeper-foo/etckeeper-bar.md ./etckeeper-foo/usrkeeper-bar.md
mv ./etckeeper-foo ./usrkeeper-foo
```

Finally. Remember, once again, that this will **fail** on esoteric filenames. Note also that if your filenames are particularly long, `xargs` will not work properly because the arguments to `mv` become too long. You can (at least on OS X) pass `-x` to `xargs` to tell it to immediately fail if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use a small script and do a `for` loop on the find results and a `mv` with a bash string replacement on the files found :

```
IFS=$'\n'
for files in $(find . -name "*etckeeper*"); 
do 
  mv "$files ${files/etckeeper/usrkeeper}"
done
```

If you don't use it in the script, then better save the original IFS and restore it at the end of the loop.

Comment: Avoid using the `for f in $(find...)` construct (it will fail if file names contain IFS characters).

Comment: yup i figured out, if we set IFS=$'\n' before the script, it won't fail. updated the script too.