# renaming file with date to a different date in shell script

Tags: linux, files, rename, date

I have files in my home dir as

```
 member_net.2017-04-20.control
 member_elig_net.2017-04-20.control
 mdcr_contractr_net.2017-04-20.control
```

I want to rename the files to a different date like in the same dir as

```
 member_net.2017-04-21.control
 member_elig_net.2017-04-21.control
 mdcr_contractr_net.2017-04-21.control
```

These files are not of 0 bytes.

Comment: assuming you want to rename all the files having date format as yyyy-mm-dd to current date right ?

Comment: @Sagar: Not necessarily the current date I think.

Comment: Lets say my files have date as 2017-04-20, I want to rename the files to a new date i.e 2017-04-21.

Comment: Related, the answers with `s/a/b/` and Bash's `${var//a/b}` work with longer strings than single characters: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19058/how-to-replace-one-char-with-another-in-all-filenames-of-the-current-directories

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If this is a one-off, I find the following process to be the best fit between convenience and robustness:

- Use ls with a pattern to select the files that you want and redirect the output to a file (the pattern is just an example, but it is not critical because of the next step):

  `ls member_net.*.control > file.list`
- Edit `file.list` in your favorite editor: get rid of any files that you don't want to change (that's why the pattern above is not critical); make sure that it includes *all* the files that you want to change, adding any missing ones by hand if necessary; change each line from `xxx` to `mv xxx XXX` where XXX is just like xxx but with the modified date. This step depends on your editor, but can also be done by using `sed` on the original file and `paste` to paste the files together:

  `sed 's/2017-04-20/2017-04-21/g' file.list > newfile.list`

  `paste file.list newfile.list > bothfiles.list`

  `sed 's/^/mv /' bothfiles.list > commands.list`
- You now should have a file `commands.list` that contains command lines of the form

  `mv OLDNAME NEWNAME`
- Check it carefully to make sure each command line is correct and complete.
- Then you can execute the commands by piping the file into your shell:

  `cat commands.list | bash`

What I find attractive is that I can check the file and make sure that it is exactly right and then *without touching it at all* execute all the commands in it and be sure that it will do the right thing.

This is not as general as writing a shell script, but it is often a useful technique to remember.

Comment: This will fail with filenames containing newlines or tabs, so it's not very general. Pasting commands to a shell also feels somewhat iffy, given that there's also a proper solution (in your other answer).

Comment: Correct: as I said it's not a general solution, but it is a useful trick to have in one's tool belt. "Pasting commands" - did you mean "Piping commands"? If so, I disagree that it is iffy: it is actually much safer than a shell script, because I can *look* at the commands *before* I execute them.

Comment: yep, I meant piping like that. You'd need to be very careful to double check the commands, otherwise you might end up running commands from the filenames. Which would not happen with a shell script that does its job properly.

Comment: I find the trick valuable in "irregular" situations where a shell script is harder to write. If it's a one-off, why bother writing the script? You'd have to   write it, test it, debug it and after all this trouble throw it away. Instead, I can write a file (or better yet write a script that writes the file) that contains exactly the commands I need and pipe it into the shell - and then throw it away.

Answer (score 2):

A different method is to write a shell script, e.g. in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.2017-04-20.* ;do
    mv "$f" "${f/2017-04-20/2017-04-21}"
done
```

It is much simpler than the other solution in this case, but I do recommend that you always keep the other solution in mind.

Comment: Why not add this as another option in your answer above?

Comment: Maybe I should, but they seemed so different from each other and I did want to highlight the `cat command.list | bash` trick in the other answer. I hoped that that would not get lost in the noise.

Answer (score 0):

With the Perl `rename` command:

```
rename -n -v 's/2017-04-20/2017-04-21/' *.control
```

(`-n` is for no-action, `-v` for verbose, so you can check what it does before actually running it.)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the shell script that will help you. You can choose different date. I used current date. Save the shell script as myrename.sh and call it `./myrename.sh dirname`. Where `dirname` is the name of directory in which files will be affected.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `ls $1 | grep -E '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'`
do
    x=`echo $i | grep -oE   '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'`
    y=`echo $i | sed "s/$x/$(date +%F)/g"`
    mv $1/$i $1/$y 2>/dev/null #incase if old date is same as current date
done
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` like that will also fail with names containing whitespace, or possibly other characters, see  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: Well yeah this is just the rough idea. Who said this is complete bullet proof source code. This  is just to give him idea how one could do it. @ikkachu